# Rails landing page password authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, erb

I want to create a 'Coming Soon' landing page for my app.  It's a fully functional app, but while we are in beta I want to have a landing page with a password to control access while we are still testing.  Once someone enters the correct password on the landing page then they can access the app.  NOTE: this landing page password is different than a user account password.

Here is my view in "landing_password.html.erb":

```
<%= simple_form_for :landing, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :text %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sign In" %>
<% end %>
```

And here is my pages_controller:

```
def landing
testpassword = 'test'
if params[:landing][:password] == testpassword
    redirect_to home_path
end
```

end

But when the password is 'correct', meaning when I type in 'test', it does not complete the redirect to home path.  Anyone know why it doesnt work?

Comment: Keep in mind that people are able to skip your authentication by guessing a correct url. A more secure approach would be to add a boolean field to the session as soon as the user logged in successfully. Then check for existance of this field in a `before_filter` at your ApplicationController. If it's nil, redirect to your landing page. Cheers.

Comment: What does 'not complete the redirect to home path' exactly mean? Do you get an error / exception displayed? If not, what happens instead?

Comment: It means that it does not redirect to the home path, it merely stays on the same page.  Good point about the before_filter...I'll try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a typo in the form definition; you use `:text`, but shouldn't that be `:password`?

```
<%= simple_form_for :landing, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :password, label: "Please enter your password" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sign In" %>
<% end %>
```